# C++ Removing Unused Class Attribute Causes std::logic_error

Tags: c++, string, class, exception, atomic

I have a class which has a few attributes like shown below, my problem is that when I remove or place the `string s` attribute before `std::atomic<char*> atomic_input` the program terminates with exception:

> 'std::logic_error'
>
> what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

```
#include <string>
#include <atomic>

// In ui.cpp
class UI
{
private:
    std::atomic<char*> atomic_input;
    std::string s; /* this can be renamed, but removing or placing it 
                      before the above field crashes the program */
};


// In main.cpp
#include "ui.cpp"
int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    initscr();          /* start the curses mode */
    UI* ui = new UI();
    return 0;
}
```

The string attribute is **not** accessed within the program in any way, renaming it is possible. The reason why I have an `atomic` field is that the value is shared among several threads.

I have tried placing the `string` field in different lines within the class attributes, the program only crashes if the declaration is **before** the `atomic_input`.

What might be causing the problem? Is it something to do with how the classes in C++ should be defined?

Comment: "What might be causing the problem?" -- Some part you didn't show us. Please provide a [mcve]. Asking "why isn't my code working?" without providing such an example is considered a reason to close the question. Also note that reducing a problem to a minimum example is a very useful and valuable debugging technique in itself. ;-)

Comment: "The string attribute is not accessed within the program in any way". Then why do you need it at all?

Comment: Something somewhere in your code has undefined behaviour. Did you remember to recompile all the code that uses this type?

Comment: Moving the declarations is likely to result in a class layout change. Perhaps you are mixing code compiled with the new layout and code compiled with the old layout?

Comment: @P.W I used it as a global variable before switching to 'atomic' variable.

Comment: @molbdnilo that might be the issue since I am only compiling the file where the main function is, how do I recompile all the files?

Comment: @gpeche how do I recompile all the files from scratch? When I run `g++ *.cpp -o out -lcurses -lmenu -lpthread` the compiler says that there are multiple definitions of functions even if there are only 1.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like I've found a solution.

`std::atomic<char*> atomic_input` not being initialized like seen below was causing the issue. I still don't know how the `string` variable was interfering with it.

My guess is that the compiler somehow interprets the `string` as a constructor for `atomic_input`. The error only occurs when `atomic_input` is accessed in runtime and not in the compilation.

```
#include <string>
#include <atomic>

// In ui.cpp
class UI
{
private:
    std::atomic<char*> atomic_input{(char*)""};
    // std::string s; /* Initializing the atomic char like above solved the problem */
};
```

Comment: If you don't know what the problem was, you haven't found a solution. (Your guess is not correct.)